# Error: String cannot be resolved to the type

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

While trying this code,it shows this error in the string line.

```
  <% 
  String error = (String)request.getAttribute("error");
  request.removeAttribute("error");
  if(error != null)
  out.println(error);
  %>
```

Thanks!

Comment: What error does it show exactly? Do you have the **stacktrace** to post here?

Comment: I believe this question is focused on references.  The assumption is that the variable error should be pointing to the "error" reference in the collection of attributes on the request.  So the question is asking - why after removing the attribute from the request is the if (error !- null) expression returning true?  If my interpretation is correct - perhaps the OP can update the question to reflect that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to get the string try this:

```
<%    
String error = (String)request.getParameter("error");   
request.removeAttribute("error");   
if(error != null)   
    out.println(error);   
%>
```

`getAttribute()` returns an Object, `getParameter` returns the Value of the Query String

Comment: Why should he use `parameter` ?